# tkinter Entry stuck in GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a simple program that will split a .mp3 into multiple pieces.
But when I am in the GUI of Tkinter the entry box is stuck at 0 with me unable to change it.

```
root = Tk()
root.wm_title('mp3 splitter')

root.fileVar = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("MP3 files","*.mp3"),("All files","*.*")))

splitVar = IntVar()
splitLabel = Label(root,text='Split by').grid(row=2,sticky=W)
splitEntry = Entry(root,width=50, textvariable=splitVar)
splitEntry.grid(row=2,column=1)

exportButtonSplit = Button(root,text='Press to split into parts',command=exportSplit).grid(row=3,sticky=W)
exportButtonSecs = Button(root,text='Press to split into seconds',command=exportSecs).grid(row=4,sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

There is no err code outputted when I run this.

I think that it is a problem with the browse files dialogue box as it worked fine when the user had to put in the directory manually.

If anyone can help please answer.

Thanks!!

Comment: Do not do `var = Widget(...).layout(...)`, or the variable get's bound to the return value of the layout method! Seems not to be the problem here, since you don't use those values at all, but don't develop the habit.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem based on the posted code. I'm able to type any value I want into the entry widget.

Comment: Where are `exportSplit` and `exportSecs`? [mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with easygui here is the entire source code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

__author__ = 'Simon Reynolds'


from tkinter import *            #GUI module
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3      #mp3 metadata extracter
from pydub import *              #can modify audio in python
from easygui import fileopenbox  #needed to open browse files
import os,sys                    #needed to make .mp3 file

#sets audio codec: should be ffmpeg because it is the one pydub is built off of
AudioSegment.converter = 'C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe'


"""---------------rename '.' files to '.mp3' in the executable directory-----------"""


 def renameFiles_mp3():
    for filename in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))): #for file in exacutable directory
        base_file, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)                            #gets file name and extention
        if ext == "":                                                       
            os.rename(filename, base_file + ".mp3")                         #if     extention = "" changes it to ".mp3"


"""-------------------devides a list (l) into n sized chunks------------------"""


def chunks(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):    #range 0 to length of list with n sized gaps
        yield l[i:i+n]               #slice list from i to i + n and returns each chunk as a elem of a list


"""-------------------split the .mp3 into defined seconds---------------------"""


def exportSecs():

    #get the native bitrate of the original .mp3 
    file_mp3 = MP3(file)
    bitrateNative = int(file_mp3.info.bitrate / 1000)

    #puts the .mp3 data into a list so it can be manipulated
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file)

    #split .mp3 into chunks
    segment_length_secs = int(splitVar.get())
    segment_length = segment_length_secs * 1000
    chunks_of_sound = chunks(sound, segment_length)

    #for loop that exports the parts
    count = 0    
    for i in chunks_of_sound:
        count += 1
        i.export("part"+str(count),format="mp3", bitrate=str(bitrateNative)+"k")

    #names the files .mp3
    renameFiles_mp3()


"""---------------------split the .mp3 into defined parts---------------------"""


 def exportSplit():

    #get the native bitrate of the original .mp3 
    file_mp3 = MP3(file)
    bitrateNative = int(file_mp3.info.bitrate / 1000)

    #puts the .mp3 data into a list so it can be manipulated
    sound = AudioSegment.from_mp3(file)

    #split .mp3 into chunks
    splitBy = splitVar.get()
    chunks_of_sound = chunks(sound, len(sound) // splitBy)

    #for loop that exports the parts
    count = 0
    for i in chunks_of_sound:
        count += 1
        i.export('part'+str(count),format='mp3', bitrate=str(bitrateNative)+"k")

    #names the files .mp3
    renameFiles_mp3()


"""------------------------------------GUI-----------------------------------"""


root = Tk()
root.wm_title('mp3 splitter')

#Define how the .mp3 will be split
splitVar = IntVar()
splitLabel = Label(root,text='Split by').grid(row=2,sticky=W)
splitEntry = Entry(root,width=50, textvariable=splitVar)
splitEntry.grid(row=2,column=1)

#divide in parts or seconds
exportButtonSplit = Button(root,text='Press to split into parts',command=exportSplit).grid(row=3,sticky=W)
exportButtonSecs = Button(root,text='Press to split into      seconds',command=exportSecs).grid(row=4,sticky=W)

#open browse files
file = fileopenbox()

root.mainloop()
```